# Structured Data Tool doesn't see JavaScript rendered content

Tags: javascript, googlebot, structured-data

Some structured data (namely price) of my page is rendered by JavaScript. According to fetching results in Webmaster tools Googlebot sees and renders it perfectly.

However the structured data tool only sees the HTTP response w/o any scripting applied.

Is it really so? Does Googlebot is more intelligent then structured data analysis and some workarounds like JSON-LD must be added?

Comment: Yes. The tool is likely not as sophisticated as googlebot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Googlebot is a kind of browser, which processes javascript the testing tool does not.

With JSON-LD, if loaded by javascript, you will achieve the same effect you get now: search console sees your structured data, the testing tool doesn't.

To make testing tool gets your data, the data must be present in the source code at the moment of testing, independently like what, json-ld or microdata.

But if you are sure, that your structured data is error-free, so let it be implemented like it currently is. Just be sure, that your javascript, which makes structured data rendering:

a) not triggered by any action, like click, scroll, onerror etc.

b) doesn't have long time gap after `onload` (sometime Googlebot will quit waiting and gets off).